# Instagram embed iframe don't render in IE8, workaround?

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-8, instagram

I want to add the embed tag of an Instagram's video into my page, but it don't render in IE 8.

The embed code looks really simple:

```
<iframe src="//instagram.com/p/ezRR6Hi93u/embed/" width="612" height="710" frameborder="0 
scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

As it works with other addresses, I'm considering some kind of conflict between protocols, although I've already tried addresses with and without SSL.

IE 8's console also shows this error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference. ui-common.js, line 2 character 19294
```

Has anybody faced the same problem or have done a workaround for this problem? How to properly use Instagram's embed code in IE8?

Comment: I guess only Instagram can fix this.